# How do i draw the contents of a BufferedImage on a VolatileImage?

Tags: java, bufferedimage

I'm currently trying to create VolatileImages in Java. the plan is to have an ImageSheet that is a BufferedImage and a method getSubimage() that returns a volatile sub-image.

```
    public static VolatileImage getSubimage( ImageSheet sheet, int x, int y, int transparency ) {

    if ( x * sheet.tilesize >= 0 && x * sheet.tilesize <= sheet.img.getWidth() 
            && y * sheet.tilesize >= 0 && y * sheet.tilesize <= sheet.img.getHeight() ) {

        BufferedImage temp = sheet.img.getSubimage( x * sheet.tilesize, y * sheet.tilesize, sheet.tilesize, sheet.tilesize );

        VolatileImage retVal = gc.createCompatibleVolatileImage( temp.getWidth(), temp.getHeight(), transparency );

        Graphics2D g2d = retVal.createGraphics();
        g2d.drawImage( temp, 0, 0, null );
        g2d.dispose();
        retVal.flush();

        return retVal;

    } else return null;

}
```

Let me explain the 2 parameters that are used but not initialized here: gc and sheet.tilesize : gc is the GraphicsConfiguration of my ScreenDevice and sheet.tilesize is a universial size used for all images in the sheet that i want to load later. For my testing purpose, it's 32 since my image has a height and a width of 32.
Now my problem is, that retVal has no content on it. I already tried to find the root of my problem via sysouts and found out that the ImageSheet gets initialized correctly and is working fine just when i try to draw it's contents on my VolatileImage it doesn't work... Does anybody see the problem and can help me?

Comment: Your drawing code seems fine, but you probably shouldn't `flush` your volatile image (`retVal`). However, one of the properties of a volatile image is that it ["is an image which can lose its contents at any time due to circumstances beyond the control of the application"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/VolatileImage.html). See the link for how to draw on it, you usually do it in a loop. Why do you want to use a `VolatileImage` in the first place?

Comment: i want to use it because it is hardware accelerated and saves some memory for the application

Comment: Sounds like premature optimization to me, but you might have special requirements and/or profiling data that makes this important.

Comment: PS: Just found [VolatileBufferedToolkitImage Strategies](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/index-141909.html) which should be a good read.